# Mongoose schema reference and undefined type 'ObjectID'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to do some relations between my schemas and I have some problems with my solution.
Here is my device schema:

```
var deviceSchema = schema({
    name : String,
    type : String,
    room: {type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,  ref: 'Room'},
    users: [{type:mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}]
});
```

and here room schema:

```
var roomSchema = schema({
    name : String,
    image : String,
    devices: [{type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Device'}]
});
```

Mongoose throws error

> TypeError: Undefined type `ObjectID` at `room`   Did you try nesting
>   Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.

If I change `room: {type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,  ref: 'Room'},` to `room: {type: Number,  ref: 'Room'},` everything works. Could you explain me why this is happening?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`mongoose.Types.ObjectId` is the `ObjectId` constructor function, what you want to use in schema definitions is `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` (or `mongoose.Schema.ObjectId`).

So `deviceSchema` should look like this instead:

```
var deviceSchema = schema({
    name : String,
    type : String,
    room: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,  ref: 'Room'},
    users: [{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}]
});
```

Comment: With `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` it's working. The weird thing is that with `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` I was able to create user object and device object and did relations between them. Error shown when I added second model (Room) and did a relation between Room and Device