# Mongoose: retrieving array of ObjectIds from collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, robo3t

My database has following type of documents for Categories collection.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56716afa403743492828aa07"),
    "cat_name" : "watches",
    "cat_parent_id" : [
        ObjectId("56716afa403743492828aa01"),
        ObjectId("56716afa403743492828aa03")
    ]
   .........
}
```

I first created database with Robomongo, then I'm trying to fetch data using mongoose and created following Schema.

```
var categorySchema = new Schema({
    'cat_name' : String,
    'cat_parent_id' : [{ type : mongoose.Types.ObjectId }],
    .......
});
```

but when I'm getting the result through following callback,

```
Categories.find(function(err,categories){........});
```

the cat_parent_id array is empty.

**Edit:**

When I replace *mongoose.Types.ObjectId* with *Schema.Types.ObjectId or String*,It works.Can anyone provide reason for that?

Comment: Shouldn't it be { type : [mongoose.Types.ObjectId] }?

Comment: Looks like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28617798/mongoose-schema-reference-and-undefined-type-objectid

Comment: The reason is that you need to use `mongoose.Schema.Types` to declare schema properties; `mongoose.Types` is meant for instantiation of particular types but is unrelated to schema setup.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add reference for the ObjectId type:

```
var categorySchema = new Schema({
   'cat_name' : String,
   'cat_parent_id' : [{
              type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
              ref: 'Categories'
              }],
   .......
});
```