# Mongoose schema TypeError :Undefined type `ObjectId` at. Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays

Tags: mongoose, schema, typeerror

While creating schema for collection and inserting document with type objectId(converting it to String) , getting Undefined type error.

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
let testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  date: {type: Date, required: true},
  test_id: {type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId().toString(), required: true},
}, {collection: 'timeslotsTest'}); 
let testModel = mongoose.model("test", testSchema);

timeslotModel.create({
  "date":"2017/11/21",
  "test_id":"1"
}
```

Comment: No you cannot do `ObjectId().toString()` here. If you want a "string" then it's `type: String` instead. But you really should leave the `ObjectId` as it is. Takes much less space and it's better that way.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to mongoDB. Curious - is  it not possible to convert ObjectId type to string or my way is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really require to give the id. It creates an id automatically. So, the below sample would help you.

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
   //username: String
username: {type: String, unique: true}
});

var JobSchema= new Schema({
name: String,
members: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'UserModel'}]
});

// Mongoose Model definition
var UserModel = mongoose.model('UserModel', UserSchema);
var JobModel= mongoose.model('JobModel', JobSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because I set `ObjectId` to sub-document Schema

```
import { ObjectID } from "mongodb";

const groupSchema = new Schema({
    group_name: String,
    members: [{
        member_id: String,
        member_name: String
    }],
    chat: [{
        _id: ObjectId, //changed to 'String', resolved this issue
        message: String,
        sender_id: String,
        status: String,
    }]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`mongoose.Types.ObjectId()`
is the constructor of ObjectId, use
`mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` instead
[Mongoose schema reference and undefined type 'ObjectID'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28617798/mongoose-schema-reference-and-undefined-type-objectid)