# Error when trying to creating relation in mongoose

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

Okay so i get this error when i am trying to create my Schema:

```
F:\web udvikling\Skole\rts-svendeprøve\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:696
throw new TypeError('Undefined type `' + name + '` at `' + path +
^
TypeError: Undefined type `undefined` at `posted`
Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.
```

This is my Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var articleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    text: String,
    posted: Date.now(),
    edits: Array,
    views: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    comments: Array,
    _author: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    _category: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Article', articleSchema);
```

I only get the error when i add my _author and _category.

I have tried following this [Mongoose schema reference and undefined type 'ObjectID'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28617798/mongoose-schema-reference-and-undefined-type-objectid)
But it didnt help, also quite a few other posts. Im not sure what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

I dun goofed big time.

My issue was not the relations, but the fact that my "posted" key was not made like this ->
posted: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }